# Checking if url exists

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

For my project I need to check a URL to see if it exists or not.
So I created a `HttpURLConnection` and connected to the url and wait for the response code.
Since I can't use that HttpURLConnection in my Main Thread, i had to move it to an AsyncTask and let it run on a separate Thread.

This is what my code for that AsyncTask looks like (only the important parts):

```
private class URLExists extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        boolean isValid = false;

        try
        {
            URL myurl = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            connection.connect();
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();

            ...

            connection.disconnect();

            if(code != 404)
                isValid = true;

            else
                isValid = false;
        }

            ...
        return isValid;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isValid)
    {
        isTrue = isValid;
    }
}
```

So basically i then get a boolean value `isTrue` which tells me if the url is valid. When I run this i get the right results, everything works.

But now, when i execute this AsyncTask, it runs parallel to my main Thread, obviously.

I have this code:

```
new URLExists().execute("https://www.example.com");
if(isTrue)
{
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do Something
            }
        });
}
```

Since my AsyncTask runs parallel, my Main Thread executes the next operation without waiting for the result of the AsyncTask. Since `isTrue` is `false` by default, the if statement never runs.

Of course i know about the `protected void onPostExecute()` in the AsyncTask, but does that mean that all the code that follows in my main Thread has to be in that function in the parallel Thread? It all depends on the outcome of the URL check.

I know about the .get() method, but that freezes my MainThread and the UI, so that's not really an option for me.

Is there any other way of making the Main thread wait for the AsyncTask? I know the defeats the purpose of the AsyncTask, but all I want is to check if the URL exists and I can only do checks in an AsyncTask.

Comment: Waiting main thread is not recommended and treated as bad user UX. You could move code about setting click listener to `onpostexecute` of `AsyncTask`. However you should somehow let user know that button will not work as would be expected. I would disable it until I got answer from network or postpone on click execution until I get answer from network. More comments about you asynctask. 404 is not only one error response code as well many webservers don't handle HEAD request correctly. So be aware about these facts

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multithread for your task. All what you need is to check that url is available. Right? Of course it may take some time and you have to wait this time in your main thread. That's right. But you still need to wait. Don't create unnecessary complexity. Just read url, get response code, validate it, check for timeout exception and you are good to go.

Comment: How? I thought I need multithreading for an AsyncTask since it wont run on the main Thread? How else can I check  if a URL exists

Comment: Just put connection.connect(); code = connection.getResponseCode();
to your code and this is good enough. However, and that's what probably confuses you, your main thread should be separated from the UI thread. In other words - don't do anything (especially time consuming like database connection or http connection) in UI thread - for example within onClick method. onClick executes within GUI thread. You can see it if you put break point - when you stop you can debug but your GUI is irresponsible. Regular practice - within onClick start another thread to do this job and  return control ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

We need to look at the specification of AsyncTask. Typically in any asynchronous method you have a callback function that lets you know the background operation has completed. In the case of Android it is `onPostExecute()`

It can be found here. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:

> 1. `onPreExecute()`, invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
>    by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
> 2. `doInBackground(Params...)`, invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>    to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>    parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>    result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>    passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>    publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>    These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>    onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
> 3. `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`, invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>    undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>    user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>    For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>    a text field.
> 4. `onPostExecute(Result)`, invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
>    computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

For your specific case you might want to do something like this..

```
yourAsyncTask{
   @Override
   protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
        // CHECK YOUR URL HERE
   }
   .
   .
   .
   @Override
   public void onPostExecute(Result result){
      if(isTrue) {
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do Something
         }
        });
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I know about onPostExecute like I said in my question before. The thing is that I have a lot of code to execute after the URL check. Do I have to put my entire Code into that onPostExecute function?

Comment: If it is code that is dependent on the response then yes it would go into the onPostExecute callback.